# LWUIT: Adding GIF Image to a label

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I am trying to add a GIF image to a label (LWUIT 1.5). When I add the Gif image to "GIF Animation", it creates timeline images (individual images). Please help me as how to add the complete GIF animated image to the label.

Note: The same was working fine when Resource editor 1.3 is used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this is what you need? [animated-gif-using-lwuit](http://ugochirico.blogspot.com/2009/11/animated-gif-using-lwuit.html)

Answer (score 2):

You get a series of images but one of them is the timeline which should animate just fine. Unlike the old LWUIT which created a single image the timeline uses a different technique to get gif's working. This works for me when selecting the animation image.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. It works fine for me now.. Many Thanks :)